Http authentication doesn't work in zabbix 6.x
I installed zabbix server 6-th version. Users created. All installed with official documentation. But http authentication doesn't working. When I try, I got error:
You are not logged in Session terminated, re-login, please. Incorrect user name or password or account is temporarily blocked.
Compare all configuration file from older zabbix 5.x version. Finded answers in internet and in official documentation.
